# Jenkins docker agent in declarative pipeline: file not found

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

When trying to execute the example from https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/wiki/Controlling-your-build-environment:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker 'node'
    }
    stages {
        stage("testing 123") {
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following output:

```
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Agent Setup)
[Pipeline] sh
[XXXXX-ABOESSRH5FV5AM3VLFMZ4UZP722N63WT5EEAE2JPIXC5U5ZTMBYA] Running shell script
+ docker pull node
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/node
Digest: sha256:a72f8cd9aba12ea3a19ada91e077c4d8822d3bd7dc3c4707b16630e5c2477845
Status: Image is up to date for node:latest
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] sh
[XXXXX-ABOESSRH5FV5AM3VLFMZ4UZP722N63WT5EEAE2JPIXC5U5ZTMBYA] Running shell script
+ docker inspect -f . node
.
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline

GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:245)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:214)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:846)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:384)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.launch(DockerClient.java:268)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.launch(DockerClient.java:249)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.launch(DockerClient.java:246)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.version(DockerClient.java:218)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.WithContainerStep$Execution.start(WithContainerStep.java:136)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:184)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:126)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image.inside(jar:file:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy:128)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker.node(jar:file:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image.inside(jar:file:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy:116)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.DockerPipelineScript.runImage(jar:file:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/impl/DockerPipelineScript.groovy:54)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.AbstractDockerPipelineScript.configureRegistry(jar:file:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/impl/AbstractDockerPipelineScript.groovy:68)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.AbstractDockerPipelineScript.run(jar:file:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/impl/AbstractDockerPipelineScript.groovy:54)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.CheckoutScript.checkoutAndRun(jar:file:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/pipeline-model-extensions/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-extensions.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/CheckoutScript.groovy:57)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.CheckoutScript.doCheckout(jar:file:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/pipeline-model-extensions/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-extensions.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/CheckoutScript.groovy:40)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.LabelScript.run(jar:file:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/impl/LabelScript.groovy:44)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor268.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:33)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:165)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:328)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:80)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:240)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:228)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:245)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:214)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:846)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:384)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.launch(DockerClient.java:268)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.launch(DockerClient.java:249)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.launch(DockerClient.java:246)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.version(DockerClient.java:218)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.WithContainerStep$Execution.start(WithContainerStep.java:136)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:184)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:126)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:18)
    ... 29 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

docker is installed on the server, and is in the PATH: the image *is* built :-) (`docker pull` command succeed at the beginning of the pipeline)

I added a logger on `org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient` with the following result:

```
Apr 07, 2017 3:56:18 PM FINE org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient
Executing docker command docker -v
```

I also tried launching a docker in a stage with a regular agent, same issue:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage("testing 123") {
      agent {
        docker {
          image 'ubuntu:16.04'
        }
      }
      steps {
        sh 'uname -a'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

using Docker.Pipeline 1.10

This seems to be related to a PATH configuration issue on the node, but I can't find where.

If I run `org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.tools.DockerTool.getExecutable("docker", Jenkins.getActiveInstance(), null, null)` in the node console, I get the correct (existing, executable) docker path.

any idea ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: is the docker daemon running?

Comment: yes. I can run docker commands in regular pipelines as well. This seems to be a PATH config issue but can't find where

Comment: Does that part of the pipeline run in a docker container? If so, is docker available in the container as well?

Comment: the pipeline is exactly the one I've put in the question. No other operation are performed (so: "launch a docker node pipeline and execute 'node --version'")

Comment: Did you solved this issue? I'm currently stuck at the same issue.

Comment: Nope, I didn't... I stopped trying to use the docker pipeline instead :-)

Comment: Try to install docker again in your Jenkins CLI. These shows your docker is not running. and after installing docker in Jenkins . use the command as `gpasswd -a jenkins docker` , it will add.

Comment: Docker was installed by the jenkins user (docker binary is owned by jenkins, with rwx rights). How do you explain the fact that `docker pull node` is successfully executed if docker is not running ?

Comment: what is the OS in jenkins slave?  Is it windows ?

Comment: Nope. Ubuntu if I recall correctly. I never ran jobs on windows

Comment: is docker in PATH for which user? for jenkins(who owns jenkins process)?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `~/.zshenv` for zshell (or other file) to put docker in the path. I did this and problem resolved:

```
$ cat ~/.zshenv
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

It looks like the `docker inspect` not run in the same env as `docker pull`.

On my Mac, the `docker pull` failed, then I configured node/agent to add such `Name: PATH, Value: /usr/local/bin:$PATH` to the `Environment variables`, then the `docker pull` will run normally. And `docker inspect` failed.

Then I add `~/.zshenv` as above (and restart node/agent), the `docker inspect` worked finally.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a shell command that is something like `sh "docker 'node'"`

What I've done is used a Jenkinsfile and Dockerfile (since I edit my images) and have the Jenkinsfile call a script that has

```
docker build --tag=image-name .
docker run --rm --name=image-name-container image-name \
./someScript.sh \
-j ${SCRIPT_PARAM1} \
-u ${SCRIPT_PARAM2} > ${DOCKER_OUTPUT_FILE_NAME}
```

inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are facing this is that as per your Jenkins file you are not able to tell Jenkins that where node is? and that's why giving such exception,I can suggest some other way like but you can do is install node on your Jenkins master, configure the path in the configuration system by installing  node plugin.Then, in the Jenkins file add below tools section at the top:

```
tools {
 node 'name-configured-in-the-configuration-system'
}
```

In this way Jenkins will know that where your node is installed and would execute the command given in the stage.

Answer (score 0):

To sperate stages and each stage its own container you can use the following style.

```
node() {
  checkout scm


  def String dockerImage = 'dockerImageName'
  def String dockerArgs = "-v ${WORKSPACE}/test:/tmp/test"

  stage ('Build') {
    docker.image(dockerImage).inside(dockerArgs) {
      echo 'Build them'
      }
    }

  stage('Test') {
    docker.image(dockerImage).inside(dockerArgs) {
      sh 'node --version'
    }

  }
}
```

If nodejs is installed in your docker image then without any issue it should work