# Jenkins - Cannot run program "docker"

Tags: bash, docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, calabash

Trying to use a docker agent with a declarative pipeline...

```
pipeline
{
    agent
    {
        docker
        {
            image 'rubygem/calabash-cucumber'
        }
    }
...
```

The build job finds the docker image but then skips all stages and quits with a Java exception:

```
[test_automation] Running shell script
+ docker pull rubygem/calabash-cucumber
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from rubygem/calabash-cucumber
Digest: sha256:cc6a06017009f0a68b93db33c2ced09a224ce2b8754efadaed16c18190e56ee4
Status: Image is up to date for rubygem/calabash-cucumber:latest
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] sh
[test_automation] Running shell script
+ docker inspect -f . rubygem/calabash-cucumber
.
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] echo
All stages finished.
[Pipeline] echo
Cleaning up workspace ...
[Pipeline] echo
Build failed!
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:245)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:214)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:850)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:384)
```

Anyone know why this happens? I've added all my bash PATH variables in Jenkins general settings, added jenkins User to staff group. None helped.

Comment: The other docker commands i.e. "docker pull" and "docker inspect" are running OK by the looks of things and so I don't think it is an issue with environmental variables or permissions. Maybe an issue with the actual script itself?

Comment: @RamanSailopal If I use `agent any` the script runs fine though.

Comment: Try adding the full path to the docker command that is failing and see if Jenkins executes it

Comment: Ok but which docker command? Because I'm not invoking docker anywhere except with the agent declaration.

Comment: Did you add jenkins to docker user group?

Comment: @LukášDoležal I listed all groups with `$dscl . list /groups` but there is no group named docker. Btw this is on Mac OSX.

Answer (score 3):

Adding ~/.zshenv for zshell (or other file) to put docker in the path. I did this and problem resolved:

```
$ cat ~/.zshenv
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

I answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44197275/2557645

Comment: Thanks @Macdao.  This is bloody true.  Before trying your solution, I checked that:    

① I have docker path configured as environment variables in node properties.
② printing debug info `sh "which docker"` and `sh "echo $PATH"` always work.

    Don't know why I need zshenv.  Better not install zsh on any Jenkins node I think.

Comment: What do you mean by "Adding ~/.zshenv"? Did you run `source ~/.zshenv`? In which stage?