# How to create a bind mount in jenkins pipeline for local maven repo

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, maven-3

I'm running jenkins without docker but am using a jenkins declarative pipeline which starts a maven docker image. I need to "link" a persistent .m2 repo outside the docker instance with the internal one which maven is downloading all the dependencies to, so that the dependencies don't have to be re-downloaded each time jenkins starts a job.

```
docker {
    image 'maven:3.6.3-jdk-8'
    args '-v $HOME/.m2:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2'
}
```

^ This is how I am currently trying to do it, but it is not working for me.
I've also tried using the root .m2 like this:

```
-v $HOME/.m2:/root/.m2
```

as https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/ demonstrates.

If it helps, this is the full command used by jenkins:

```
docker run -t -d -u 112:119 -v $HOME/.m2:/root/.m2 -w /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CITestingRepo_master -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CITestingRepo_master:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CITestingRepo_master:rw,z -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CITestingRepo_master@tmp:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CITestingRepo_master@tmp:rw,z -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** maven:3.6.3-jdk-8 cat
```

How do I correctly make the .m2 repo persist accross any job which I run using these settings?

Comment: Did you try to mount any other files? try to mount a simple .txt file to your container and check if it mounted. if it is, then the problem is with your configuration

Comment: Look at this syntax it may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43280343/jenkins-docker-agent-in-declarative-pipeline-file-not-found/64813655#64813655

Comment: Ok so I figured out why this wasn't working. The docker container has no $HOME, and installs the .m2 repo to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/"reponame_branch"/?/ Very strange issue, no clue why it does this. And I don't know how to fix it.